# How to study Euclidean geometry from axioms?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, axioms, plane-geometry, axiomatic-geometry

I want to know if there's a good book or any other type of guide to study Euclidean geometry by only the 5 axioms in plane geometry and prove every other theorems from them?

Answer (score 4):

Of course, Euclid's *Elements* were written starting from those axioms. But we know now that Euclid did not use only those axioms. More precisely, he used other axioms implicitely. I suggest that you take a look at Robin Hartshone's *Geometry: Euclid and Beyond* or at David Hilbert's *Foundations of Geometry*.

Comment: The chapter Ordered Geometry in the book Introduction To Geometry, by Coxeter, is axiom-based. Euclid makes implicit assumptions about "betweenness"..... In elliptic  geometry  you can have three  points on a line, all equidistant from each other,  and it doesn't mean much to say whether any one of them is  between the other two.......+1

Comment: Who is the author of Euclid's Elements?

Comment: I think that it's a safe bet to say that Euclid wrote Euclid's *Elements*.

Comment: The other two book you offered match my criteria?

Comment: No, since the authors of both books know that other axioms are needed.

Comment: Is it the book you had in mind? https://www.amazon.com/Euclids-Elements-Euclid/dp/1888009195/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8

Comment: Yes, it is that one.

Comment: See as well https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2828781